# WP Dashboard language changed to german after db crashed

Tags: wordpress

While working on my wordpress project, the database stopped working for a short amount of time. After getting it back up, the language in the WP dashboard changed to german. I've checked the settings and it is already set to English, tried setting it to something else and change it back but nothing seems to happen.
I've also tried defining the language in wp-config.php but no luck.

```
define('WPLANG','en_US');
```

If you have any ideas please share. Thank you

Comment: Check if your Wordpress install is corrupted by reinstalling the core files. If you have the database backed up, try restoring it to see if it has an effect. I suppose either the Wordpress files are corrupted or the database itself is.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, the language in the user panel was changed.